# Pattern matching the tag of a tagged union enum

Tags: rust

Is there a way to extract the tag of an enum to, e.g., use it as an index?

I'd like to have a vector of vectors classified by enum type, i.e., if I had:

```
enum Test {
    Point {
        x: i32,
        y: i32,
    },
    Point2 {
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
    },
    Number(i32),
}
```

I may want a vector like this:

```
[[Test::Point{1, 2}, Test::Point{3, 4}], [Test::Number(1), Test::Number(2)]]
```

I'd like to dynamically add to this vector of vectors given new values. So if a function was passed in a `Test::Number`, it would go in the second array.

Certainly in the worst case I could explicitly pattern match every possible union value, but for large enums that would get rather verbose and repetitive since all the cases would just end up as

```
match e {
    Test::Point { _, _ } => v[0].push(e),
    Test::Point2 { _, _ } => v[1].push(e),
    Test::Number(_) => v[2].push(e),
    // imagine a lot of these
}
```

I've tried a lot of syntax permutations, but I haven't gotten anything that will compile. Is there a way to treat the enum struct tags like, well, an enumeration? It looks like there's a `FromPrimitive` derive, but it's unstable and doesn't work on struct enums.

(I suppose an alternative question if you can't is if you can write a macro to autowrite that match).

Comment: you might be interested in https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/639

Answer (score 3):

You can use `..` to ignore all fields of an enum, no matter how many there are, and you can import variants from inside the `enum`s namespace with `use`. E.g

```
enum Foo {
   X { i: u8 },
   Y(u8),
   Z
}

fn bar(x: Foo) -> u32 {
    use Foo::*;
    match x {
        X { .. } => 100,
        Y(..) => 3,
        Z => 12,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternation syntax (via `|`) in the match arms and methods on the enum to reduce code duplication:

```
enum Test {
    Point1,
    Point2,
    Point3,
    Point4,
    Number1,
    Number2,
    Number3,
    Number4,
}

impl Test {
    fn bucket(&self) -> u8 {
        use Test::*;
        match *self {
            Point1 | Point2 | Point3 | Point4 => 0,
            Number1 | Number2 | Number3 | Number4 => 1,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my question may not have been entirely clear. I basically want to use the **name** as an index. So Point1, Point2, Point3 etc are all their own unique IDs.

I basically want a map of each unique enum value to a u32, I guess. A function and pattern matching is acceptable, but this doesn't really condense it in my case.

Comment: @Jsor writing all that out once as a method on the enum value still reduces code duplication, but leaves one verbose method.

Comment: I guess the issue is I want to be able to add to the enum without also changing code somewhere else. Though I guess at least the compiler will bother me about not being exhaustive if I forget.